# Send data to Datadog using Go

Tags: go, datadog

i'm collect data using Go and want to visualize it, i chose Datadog, but didn't find examples or live projects where Go used for sending metrics to Datadog. But in offical site says that Go is supported.

Comment: What kind of data did you collect? If it's generic enough, you might want to have a look at [telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) instead of rolling your own. It's a plugin-driven tool for collecting and distributing metrics. Among others it has a datadog output plugin. If you need to collected custom, specialized metrics you might want to have a look at [this client](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-go) to get an idea.

Comment: Just saw the client was already linked in the answer below. You can just look at the example on GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

First step is to install the DataDog agent on the server in which you are running your application:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/

You then need to enable the `DogStatsD` service in the DataDog agent:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/

After that, you can send metrics to the `statsd` agent using any Go library that connects to `statsd`.

For example:

https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-go

https://github.com/go-kit/kit/tree/master/metrics/statsd

Here's an example program sending some counts using the first library:

```
import (
    "github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/statsd"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    // Create the client
    c, err := statsd.New("127.0.0.1:8125")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Prefix every metric with the app name
    c.Namespace = "myapp."
    // Count two events
    err = c.Count("my_counter", 2, nil, 1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Close the client
    err = c.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, about agent and DogStatsD i understand, but example of **full** Go program i still not find

Comment: @TalkingJson: edited my answer to include an example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a convenience wrapper for DD. It uses ENV vars to configure it, but it's a nice utility to package out common DD calls once you have the agent running in the background.

```
package datadog

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "sort"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/statsd"
)

var (
    mu     sync.RWMutex
    client = newClient()

    GlobalTags Tags = Tags{}
)

// Sometimes, the connection to datadog can fail, but because UDP is connectionless, we don't get insight into
// those failures. This loop just makes sure that once a minute, the client is refreshed.
func init() {
    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(time.Minute) {
            c := newClient()
            if c != nil {
                mu.Lock()
                client = c
                mu.Unlock()
            }
        }
    }()
}

func newClient() *statsd.Client {
    hp := os.Getenv("DOGSTATSD_HOST_PORT")
    if hp == "" {
        hp = "127.0.0.1:8125"
    }

    c, err := statsd.New(hp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("stat/datadog", "Could not create a datadog statsd client.", "error", err)
    }

    return c
}

type Tags map[string]string

func (tags Tags) StringSlice() []string {
    var stringSlice []string
    for k, v := range tags {
        if k != "" && v != "" {
            stringSlice = append(stringSlice, formatName(k)+":"+formatName(v))
        }
    }
    sort.Strings(stringSlice)
    return stringSlice
}

func mergeTags(tagsSlice []Tags) Tags {
    merged := Tags{}
    for k, v := range GlobalTags {
        merged[formatName(k)] = formatName(v)
    }
    for _, tags := range tagsSlice {
        for k, v := range tags {
            merged[formatName(k)] = formatName(v)
        }
    }
    return merged
}

func Gauge(name string, value float64, tags ...Tags) error {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()
    if client == nil {
        return errors.New("datadog: nil client")
    }
    return client.Gauge(formatName(name), value, mergeTags(tags).StringSlice(), 1)
}

func Count(name string, value int64, tags ...Tags) error {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()
    if client == nil {
        return errors.New("datadog: nil client")
    }
    return client.Count(formatName(name), value, mergeTags(tags).StringSlice(), 1)
}

func Histogram(name string, value float64, tags ...Tags) error {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()
    if client == nil {
        return errors.New("datadog: nil client")
    }
    return client.Histogram(formatName(name), value, mergeTags(tags).StringSlice(), 1)
}

func Incr(name string, tags ...Tags) error {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()
    if client == nil {
        return errors.New("datadog: nil client")
    }
    return client.Incr(formatName(name), mergeTags(tags).StringSlice(), 1)
}

func Decr(name string, tags ...Tags) error {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()
    if client == nil {
        return errors.New("datadog: nil client")
    }
    return client.Decr(formatName(name), mergeTags(tags).StringSlice(), 1)
}

func Set(name string, value string, tags ...Tags) error {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()
    if client == nil {
        return errors.New("datadog: nil client")
    }
    return client.Set(formatName(name), value, mergeTags(tags).StringSlice(), 1)
}

func Timing(name string, value time.Duration, tags ...Tags) error {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()
    if client == nil {
        return errors.New("datadog: nil client")
    }
    return client.Timing(formatName(name), value, mergeTags(tags).StringSlice(), 1)
}

// Datadog allows '.', '_' and alphas only.
// If we don't validate this here then the datadog error logs can fill up disk really quickly
var nameRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`[^\._a-zA-Z0-9]+`)

func formatName(name string) string {
    return nameRegex.ReplaceAllString(name, "_")
}
```