# No metrics showing on Datadog

Tags: go, kubernetes, datadog

I am trying to send metrics generated from my Go microservice similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124961/send-data-to-datadog-using-go)-

```golang
import (
    "github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/statsd"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    // Create the client
    c, err := statsd.New("127.0.0.1:8125")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Prefix every metric with the app name
    c.Namespace = "myapp."
    // Count two events
    err = c.Count("my_counter", 2, nil, 1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Close the client
    err = c.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I am using Gitlab to push the image into Azure Container Registry and eventually deploying it into my Kubernetes cluster. I am able to see the logs for this microservice, but not being able to see the custom metrics generated. I have already set the `hostPort` as mentioned [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/?tab=kubernetes) for the Kubernetes agent setup. Any help in finding the cause of the error will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was there since I did not add the host information in the application manifest. I followed this [link](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-kubernetes-docker/) which solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).